# Balance does not match incoming transactions

Tags: rinkeby, akasha

In my akasha account - I currently have a balance of ~40(test)ETH:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x925770eee9e66e7f628fbf9244f2888fb0a5d36f

But I only see one incoming transaction of 4.2(test)ETH

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/txs?a=0x925770eee9e66e7f628fbf9244f2888fb0a5d36f

Can someone explain what is going on there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've sent you 8 AETH and 32 ETH yesterday as a tip https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xbb7323b02276aeed76b22fa50e2eefb76d5647560b8c15f23541ec5990d0e855. Etherscan doesn't report internal transactions on Rinkeby.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Etherscan only shows transactions where the account in question was the originator or the recipient. If ether is sent to you via a smart contract in a transaction you didn't create, then I don't think there's an easy way to see that transaction on Etherscan.

Comment: Those transfers should show up under the "internal transactions" on etherscan

Comment: @flygoing Some types do, yes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure etherscan shows all calls that include eth. It doesn't show the calls with 0 eth, though.

Comment: No, it doesn't. For example, the link provided in this question. :-)

Comment: I don't have time to test the variations, but notably, I'm pretty sure `selfdestruct`s don't show up, yet they transfer ether.